# mv fails but cp succeeds on nfs mount

Tags: nfs, centos7, cp, mv

I am trying to move a file from a local directory to an nfs mounted directory on a CentOS 7 server. The export is provided by FreeNAS.

Both directories are owned by the current user with at least 755 (nfs shows as 777 but I'm not sure I believe it).

My fstab looks like this

```
host:/path/to/export /mnt/nfs         nfs     defaults        0 0
```

I cannot move the file

```
mv /local/file /mnt/nfs/file
mv: cannot create regular file 'file': Operation not permitted
```

However I can copy and remove it

```
cp /local/file /mnt/nfs/file
rm /local/file
```

Output of `mount`

```
host:/path/to/export on /mnt/nfs type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=host,mountvers=3,mountport=908,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=host)
```

Directory permissions on the client

```
ls -ld /local /mnt/nfs
drwxrwxrwx. 15 user user 17 Nov 28 08:32 /mnt/nfs/
drwxrwxrwx. 2  root root 17 Nov 29 12:20 /local
```

After further investigation this seems to be regarding changing permissions. `mv` takes the permissions of the file with it, however `cp` creates a new file which inherits permissions from the parent directory. It appears the nfs mount does not allow me to `chown` files even if I am root or the owner of the files. So now my question is how do I allow the changing of permissions, or ignore the permissions given in the `mv`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount` ?

Comment: @shodanshok done! see update 2

Comment: Uhm, nothing interesting in it :( ... Did you have access to the server-side logs and/or to the `/etc/exports` file? Another thing: does it change anything to `mv` a file as a normal user (**not** root) ?

Comment: sounds like you are missing **no_root_squash** export option

Comment: I am not root when doing this. I am the user who own the directory (UID 1001). The mount is being served by my FreeNAS box.

Comment: Can you provide the status of `getenforce` if its enforcing retry the work and provide the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc`.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Yes it is enforcing, however when running your `ausearch` command after getting an `Operation not permitted` it returns `<no matches>`.

Comment: @MatthewIfe also if I disable SELinux I still get the same errors.

Comment: Can you supply the `ls -ld` output of `/local` and `/mnt/nfs`

Comment: @MatthewIfe `drwxrwxrwx. 15 user user 17 Nov 28 08:32 /mnt/nfs/` `drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 17 Nov 29 12:20 /local`

Comment: If it's a permissions thing, do you get the same error with `cp -p` instead of `cp`? Can you provide `ls -l /local/file` please (I'm interested in the permissions set)

Comment: Can you try this on the NFS server? `all_squash,anongid=0,anonuid=0`

Comment: @roaima `cp -p` succeeds but the permissions are ignored. The file I'm copying is `-rw-rw-r--. 1 jacob jacob 6 Nov 28 08:25 /tmp/test` and after the `cp -p` it is written as `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 6 Nov 28 08:25 test`.

Comment: @mzhaase In FreeNAS the 'Map All User' and 'Map All Group' settings are already set to uid 1001 (the owner of the files). Which I think achieves the same thing.

Comment: @JacobTomlinson this is really strange. Across filesystems `mv a b` is equivalent to `cp -p a b && rm a`

Comment: @roaima that's exactly what I though. There must be some subtle difference.

Answer (score 3):

- Are your password / group databases in sync between client and
  server?
- Do you see any files on nfs mounted directory on nfs client as owned
  by

  `nobody nobody`
- Can you post output of `nfsidmap -d` from server and client? Hint - when using NFSV4 outputs should match.

Most likely you are running into discrepancy between UID / GID on the NFS server and NFS client. I will show how this works based on a simple example.

Let's say you are sharing on your NFS client /nfs_share like this. Notice that `nfs_share` is writeable by anyone(777).

```
[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# cat /etc/exports
/nfs_share      192.168.0.52(rw,no_root_squash) 

[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# ls -ld /nfs_share
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 4096 Nov 30 23:55 /nfs_share
```

And mounting on your NFS Client like this

```
mount 192.168.0.51:/nfs_share /mnt
```

Now you have on nfs server user called dmitry

```
[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# getent passwd|grep dmitry
dmitry:x:500:500::/home/dmitry:/bin/bash
[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# getent group|grep dmitry
dmitry:x:500:
```

And on your nfs client you have user helen

```
[root@nfsclient ~]# getent passwd|grep helen
helen:x:500:500::/home/helen:/bin/bash
[root@nfsclient ~]# getent group|grep helen
helen:x:500:
```

Notice that despite those are different users - they have same UID and GID.
So what happens if I touch as user helen file on nfs share?

```
[helen@nfsclient mnt]$ touch helen_client
[helen@nfsclient mnt]$ ls -lrt
[helen@nfsclient mnt]$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nobody nobody 0 Nov 30 23:58 helen_client
```

On NFS client this new file will show up as owned by `nobody nobody`. This is because nfsidmap can't map client_user_name@domain  to server_user_name @domain. 
And now moment of truce. Let's check what's the file owner on the nfs server.

```
[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# ls -rlt
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dmitry dmitry 0 Nov 30 23:58 helen_client
```

Surprised yet?
Yet there is nothing strange actually. This works as expected.
NFS server can't map user helen, but what it received is UID and GID. So it created file (since folder is world writeable) with UID 500 and GID 500, which is mapped to dmitry:dmitry on NFS server.

Now let's say we have other user who's UID / GID and names match between server and client

```
[root@nfsserver mnt]# getent passwd|grep angelina
angelina:x:501:501::/home/angelina:/bin/bash
[root@nfsserver mnt]# getent group|grep angelina
angelina:x:501:

[angelina@nfsclient mnt]$ getent passwd|grep angelina
angelina:x:501:501::/home/angelina:/bin/bash
[angelina@nfsclient mnt]$ getent group|grep angelina
angelina:x:501:
```

And if I touch file on nfs client as user angelina - I will see correct user name / group on both Server and Client

```
[angelina@nfsclient mnt]$ pwd
/mnt
[angelina@nfsclient mnt]$ touch angelina_1
[angelina@nfsclient mnt]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 angelina angelina 0 Dec  1  2016 angelina_1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nobody   nobody   0 Dec  1 00:16 helen_1

[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# pwd
/nfs_share
[root@nfsserver nfs_share]# ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 angelina angelina 0 Dec  1 00:27 angelina_1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dmitry   dmitry   0 Dec  1 00:16 helen_1
```

Bottom line is for NFSV4 to work correctly you need to have

- Server and client password / group database in sync. Preferably use ldap.
- client and server should agree on the common domain name `nfsidmap -d`

Comment: The `mount` flags show the OP is using NFSv3 so some of this answer is not really relevant here

Comment: `nfsidmap` is not relevant, but on nfsv3 same id mapping is performed by `rpcidmapd`. Actually sorry, that's Linux flavor dependent. Still nfsv4 applicable. So yes, some of the answers are not applicable to v3, however what I described about importance of syncronized password dbs is till valid.

Comment: Both systems have a user with uid 1001 and gid 1001. However the username is different. All files are owned by uid 1001 on the host system.

Comment: For NFSv3 at least, it's only the UIDs/GIDs that matter

Comment: Sadly this answer didn't solve my problem. But it's a well written and thought out answer and the bounty period is over, so I'm going to award it to you.

Comment: What release of FreeNas do you have? Is it stable 9.10 or beta?